# how to get href path in next activity on click function in Android

Tags: java, android

```
    <html>


    <a href="\\\\192.168.1.102\\\\Data\\ACT\\OTHERACTS\\HTMLFILES\\2009\\ftn1acsdiv2.htm");'><span class=GramE>1a</span></a></sup>[(</span><i><span
    style='mso-bidi-font-family:AsterV'>ca</span></i><span 
style='mso-bidi-font-family:
    AsterV'>)<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>  
</span>“firm” shall have the meaning
    assigned to it in section 4 of the Indian Partnership Act, 1932 (9 of 1932),
    and includes,—<o:p></o:p>
</span></p>
     </html>

in this 1a[(ca)  is click able . this is Html content i want to print
 <a href="\\\\192.168.1.102\\\\Data\\ACT\\OTHERACTS\\HTMLFILES\\2009\\ftn1csdiv2.htm");'> its file path in another activity on click
```

function i have dynamic href how i ll get its path in another activity in android

Comment: question is about parsing or passing data?

Comment: Unrelated remark: the path separator in URIs is `/` not `\\`.

Comment: its reading content HTML in that html some where anchor tag within that href="\\\192.168.....> cms is Path is there i want to get all path in another activity suppose we ll click in first href then \\\ 192.168.1.. will PRint in another activity

Answer (score 0):

hello @Joan i think just extract the link and pass it through intent is enough. or first send it through intent to another activity and then extract. if i am not wrongly understand the question.

Comment: deepika actually i have already read this HTML and able to display in web view But in that there is some Href link when i clcik on that then it display  in another activity  i have seprte HTML for all href

Answer (score 0):

What I understand based on your comments, you want to open each link that the webview contains in a new activity(maybe having another webivew) . Right?

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {            
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Bundle b = new Bundle();                
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyThisActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class);
            b.putString("newURL", url);                
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually i have to display href path in another activity suppose if 5 href in Htm so if we ll clcik on first href then its give first href path and print that path in another activity same if clcik on second then it display second href path in another activty like so on...

Comment: then you could place some logic inside that method that determines which link has been clicked. You can use a `if else` for this. And based on that logic you can open the desired activity.